# Getting multiple float input using scanf but the input is allocated only to 1st variable

Tags: c, input, floating-point, scanf, garbage

```
main() {
    float n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, agg_mrk, prcnt;
    printf("Enter the marks of five students ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);
    printf("the five number entered by u is %f, %f, %f,%f, %f", n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
    agg_mrk = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
    prcnt = agg_mrk / 5;
    printf("The aggregate marks is %lf and the percentage is %f", agg_mrk, prcnt);
}
```

The first number is getting right value but all other numbers (`n2`, `n3`, `n4`, `n5`) showing garbage value:

[image: The first input is correct but all other input giving garbage value]

Comment: Your `scanf` format string expects commas in the input yet you don't enter any. Always check the return value of `scanf` before using any values it has read.

Comment: Thanks... i didn't know this property of scanf..

Comment: To check the return value only I have written "the five number entered by u"..

Comment: That's not checking the return value. This: `int r = scanf(..); if (r != 5) { /* error */ }`

Answer (score 2):

The input `67 78 90 56 78` does not match the expected syntax:

```
scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);
```

`scanf()` skips any leading white space, then expects a float value, then expects a `,`, then ignores whitespace, then expects another float value, etc.

The input `67 78 90 56 78` does not have a comma after the first number so `scanf()` stops converting and returns `1`, the number of successful conversions.

The values of `n2`, `n3`, `n4` and `n5` are unchanged, hence stay uninitialized, appearing as random values.

Note also that `main` must be defined with a return type of `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, agg_mrk, prcnt;
    printf("Enter the marks of five students: ");
    if (scanf("%f %f %f %f %f", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5) != 5) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    } else {
        printf("the five number entered by u is %f, %f, %f,%f, %f\n",
               n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        agg_mrk = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
        prcnt = agg_mrk / 5;
        printf("The aggregate marks is %f and the percentage is %f\n",
               agg_mrk, prcnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I understood the functionality of scanf()... int before main () is not necessary since it's a c program not c++

Comment: `int` before `main` **is** necessary for a correct C program. Implicit type is an obsolete feature of pre-ANSI C dating more than 30 years ago. Your compiler is permissive, but you should learn and use the current version of the C language.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead in 4th line:

```
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);
```

So you can clearly see, when you put "," after %input, it expects a variable or a memory to store it into.
Don't confuse scanf with printf, below code will work correctly with commas too.

```
printf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
```

I hope that you are able to spot the difference now.